# Как освободить файл от процесса, который им занят?

Tags: c#, файлы, потоки-данных, move

Вываливается исключение при попытке переместить файлы:
**System.IO.IOException:** *"Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом."*

```
//файлы картинок для перемещения 
string[] imgs = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

//кастомный юзер-контрол для отображения сетки превью картинок
// Если отключить этот блок использования картинок в превью, то перемещение работает.
ListItem_UserControl[] listItems = new ListItem_UserControl[imgs.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Length; i++)
{
    listItems[i] = new ListItem_UserControl();
    Image img;
    img = Image.FromFile(imgs[i]);
    listItems[i].Icon = img;

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listItems[i]);
}
....
// попытка подчистить контрол перед перемещением файлов тоже не дает результата
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
...
//перемещение
File.Move(path, path2);
```

Мне нужно переместить файлы в зависимости от их атрибутов и отобразив их в интерфейсе. Вроде бы в этом случае больше подходит FileInfo. Там и атрибуты можно достать, и есть метод MoveTo. Пробовал копировать файл, и удалять исходный - не подходит. В копии дата создания файла уже новая стоит, а при перемещении старая, как и нужно. К сожалению пока не получилось понять, как адаптировать под мою задачу все найденные мной туторы про файловые потоки. **Подскажите, в каком направлении копать.** А то пока у меня только костыльный вариант решения - сначала собрать файлы в зависимости от их атрибутов по спискам, затем эти списки вынести в текстовый файл. Затем уже второй половиной софтинки распарсить эти текстовые файлы и переместить по нужным папкам файлы из списков в них, маразм в общем)))

Comment: Вот почему так - мучаюсь, ищу ответ, пробую варианты, а стоит только задать вопрос - часто нахожу решение.  Сработало посмотреть в методах Image. Нашел там метод `Image.FromStream()` вместо `Image.FromFile()`, ну и создал этот поток до этого куска и закрыл после. `    var stream = File.OpenRead(imgs[i]);    img = Image.FromStream(stream);    stream.Close();`

Comment: `FileStream` является [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8). Почитайте статью по ссылке обязательно и внимательно.

Comment: Вы вполне можете опубликовать в качестве ответа то, что написали в комментарии. И потом принять его.

Comment: @aepot Благодарю, изучу

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Так и сделаю, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Length; i++)
{
    listItems[i] = new ListItem_UserControl();
    Image img;
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(imgs[i]))
    {
        img = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
    listItems[i].Icon = img;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listItems[i]);
}
```

Comment: Я исправил вам код для корректной работы с `IDisposable` `FileStream`. `stream.Close()` в исправленном варианте вызывать не нужно.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо!